# Не вижу событий переименования

Tags: debian, samba

Всем добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, хочу настроить аудит пользователей в samba вот конфиги :

```
log level = 1 vfs:1
full_audit:prefix = %u|%S
full_audit:success = mkdirat mknodat ntimes open read pwrite sendfile unlinkat unlink write rename
```

Вижу все необходимые действия кроме как переименования и перемещения файла. Подскадите как можно это можно отследить что файл А был переименован в файл Б

Версия samba 4.13.13

ОС : Debian 11